# Implement form within a php variables - PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Within my project I have implemented a data table where the id of the field that is shown inside the data table, is regulated by a checkbox, and the user has the possibility of being able to select the checkbox that obviously as mentioned above is related to the ID and click on the button extract in Excel, so as to have created a custom data extraction in `.xls`.

Also a store locator, the idea was to be able to implement this possibility within the results in the store locator, in order to create the extraction in excel format I used this form here:

```
<form action="excel_specifico.php" method="POST">
<input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="submit" value="Excel Specifico" class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>
<?php $id = $row["id"]; ?>
<?php echo "<input  type='checkbox' name='estrai[$id]' value='1' class='form-check-input' id='$id'>  " ?>
<?php echo "<label class='form-check-label' for='$id'</label>"; ?> 
</form>
```

The function instead of regulating the extraction from the db in the store locator is this:

```
function get_sidebar_display_1($criteria=array()) {
$locations = $criteria['locations'];
$lat = $criteria['lat'];
$lng = $criteria['lng'];

for($i=0; $i<count($locations);$i++) {
$name = $locations[$i]['address'];
$logo = $locations[$i]['logo'];
$url = $locations[$i]['url'];
$address = $locations[$i]['address'];
$tel = $locations[$i]['tel'];
$email = $locations[$i]['email'];
$category_id = $locations[$i]['category_id'];
$distance = round($locations[$i]['distance'],1);

$d .= '<div class="store_locator_sidebar_entry sidebar_entry_btn" data-id="'.$locations[$i]['id'].'" data-lat="'.$locations[$i]['lat'].'" data-lng="'.$locations[$i]['lng'].'">';

if($logo!='') {
$d .= '<img src="'.$logo.'" style="padding-right:5px;" align="left"> ';
}

if($url=='') $d .= '<b>'.$name.'</b>';
else $d .= '<b>'.$name.'</b>';

$d .= '<br>'.$address.'';

if($lat!='' && $lng!='') $d .= ' (<span class="store_locator_sidebar_entry_distance">'.$distance.' '.$GLOBALS['distance_unit'].'</span>)';

$d .= '</div>';

//Marker Info Window
//$d .= '<div style="display:none;" id="marker_content_'.$locations[$i]['id'].'">'.get_marker_content($locations[$i]).'</div>';
}
return $d;
}
```

I tried to implement the form in the function `get_sidebar_display_1` and this is the result:

```
function get_sidebar_display_1($criteria=array()) {

$locations = $criteria['locations'];
$lat = $criteria['lat'];
$lng = $criteria['lng'];


$d .=  '<form action="excel_specifico.php" method="POST">';
$d .=  '<input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="submit" value="Excel Specifico">';

for($i=0; $i<count($locations);$i++) {
$id = $locations[$i]['id'];
$name = $locations[$i]['address'];
$logo = $locations[$i]['logo'];
$url = $locations[$i]['url'];
$address = $locations[$i]['address'];
$tel = $locations[$i]['tel'];
$email = $locations[$i]['email'];
$category_id = $locations[$i]['category_id'];
$distance = round($locations[$i]['distance'],1);

$d .= '<div class="store_locator_sidebar_entry sidebar_entry_btn" data-id="'.$locations[$i]['id'].'" data-lat="'.$locations[$i]['lat'].'" data-lng="'.$locations[$i]['lng'].'">
<input  type="checkbox" name="estrai[$id]" value="1" class="form-check-input" id="$id">
<img src="'.$logo.'" style="padding-right:5px;" align="left">
<b>'.$name.'</b>
<br>'.$address.'
<span class="store_locator_sidebar_entry_distance">'.$distance.' '.$GLOBALS['distance_unit'].'</span>
</div>';


//Marker Info Window
//$d .= '<div style="display:none;" id="marker_content_'.$locations[$i]['id'].'">'.get_marker_content($locations[$i]).'</div>';
}

return $d .'</form>';
}
```

The problem is that the checkbox is correctly shown on the screen, but it is not selectable, where am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't appear as though your checkbox is disabled or anything, and if the checkbox is correctly shown on the screen, it's unlikely to be a PHP / HTML issue. The issue is more likely with CSS. Do you have any elements that are overlapping the `<input>`? Check the F12 Developer Tools for invisible elements that you might be clicking on instead.

Comment: @ObsidianAge look I set to the input of the checkbox a value of z-index: 9999 but in any case it is shown on the screen but not selectable